# Javascript object range

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, range

I have a javascript array of objects:

```
[
   Object { from="0", to="350", price="25"}, 
   Object { from="351", to="700", price="50"}
   ...
   Object { from="701", to="*", price="75"} // Where * - unlimited value
]
```

And input value: var total = 100

How can I find a price value?

Example: For total = 100 my price value will be 25.

Comment: How about a for loop containing an if test with >= and <=? What have _you_ tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ranges = [
    { from:0, to:350, price:25},
    { from:351, to:700, price:50},
    { from:701, to:"*", price:75}
];    

function isInRange(range, value) {
    return range.from < value && (range.to === '*' || range.to >= value)
}

var value = 100;
var priceFound = false
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length && !priceFound; i++) {
    var range = ranges[i];
    if (isInRange(range, value)) {
        alert("price: " + range.price);
        priceFound = true
    }
}
```

I cleaned up your objects definitions because your current version isn't valid javascript.